# How do you communicate to a user that their money will not be available because of a technical limitation?

Tags: user-expectation, error-message, workflow, payment

We have a feature that allows a user to add a button where they can accept online payments. The payments are processed via Stripe.

It's pretty straightforward - user creates a payment button, user connects to Stripe, user can then start accepting donations.

However, the issue here is that there are certain countries where Stripe isn't available. Ideally, we hide this feature in countries where Stripe is unavailable, but *there is a technical limitation at the moment where this cannot be addressed.*

Here's the scenario:

1. User adds a payment button.
2. A customer of theirs makes a payment.
3. If we detect that this user has integrated with Stripe, then the payment appears in their account without a problem.

But, if a Stripe connection isn't detected, the user gets an email saying, "You've received a donation. To claim your funds, please sign-up for a Stripe account."

While this wouldn't be an issue for many as they can just connect to Stripe as next steps, the problem is if/when Stripe isn't available in their country - ie: "You have funds, but unfortunately, there is no way to claim them because Stripe isn't available in your country."

What would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: You're letting users accept payments through Stripe before they have a Stripe account? This seems like a mistake, shouldn't they only be able to add a payment button after they create/verify their Stripe account?

Comment: Any emails I get that say "click here to claim your money" go straight to the trash.

Comment: @maxathousand Yes, I agree, but I would argue that since the user created these payment button(s), we set an expectation that payment could come at any time.

Comment: @DasBeasto Yes. In a perfect world, it'll work like PayPal where you can send payments to any email address. If an email address isn't associated with a PayPal account, then they just sign-up for one, hence acquiring that new user. If they aren't eligible because of their location, then they cannot sign-up for an account/claim the funds; sender can then cancel the transaction.

Comment: Can you at least get their phone number so that you can send an SMS or a message on WhatsApp? Email will be a bad idea having high chances of it being considered a spam, unless you format it properly like a marketing-email with impressive graphics.

Comment: Also, it will be a good idea to let users know very clearly what are the operating countries.

Answer (score 5):

I feel like you're going about this the wrong way, you should ask the creator of the button, prior to any implementation, the questions if it fundamentally relies on them being in the right country and having registered for Stripe, something like this:

[image]

This prevents them from placing a button that potentially would not work, on their site in the first place.

Now, it's not clear from what you have said as to what the workaround is if they don't have a Stripe account or is the proviso to use your service that they must have one? These details would form part of the solution.

Comment: This. The worst idea is to let a user go through with signing up for a service just to find out at the end that they cannot use the service or a major feature on it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Our service would still be usable; it is available everywhere. It's only this feature that would be inaccessible to certain countries due to Stripe dependency.

Comment: If they can't get their money, it's not usable.